# I would to add integer to the path in firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
for(int i = 0; int.parse(data['bedsAvailable']) > i; i++)
  //if((data.data() as Map)['boarderId'+'1'] != null)
  Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16).copyWith(bottom: 0),
    child: Text(data['boarderId'+i.toString()],
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.green),
    ),
  )
```

In every boarder Entered the room new boarderId created in the firestore.

I would like to display all the data in everyBoarderId in every loop.

Comment: Sounds like a fun use-case. What is the problem with the code you shared? Is there an error message?

Comment: You may check the following links as well:
[Flutter position fixed equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49566752/flutter-position-fixed-equivalent)
[How do I padd a non string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419908/how-do-i-pass-non-string-data-to-a-named-route-in-flutter)
[Add items inside an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74406194/i-want-to-add-items-inside-an-array)
[Type string cannot be added to parameter data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67651069/the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-data)